# Queue build on Jenkins. Trigger it manually

Tags: jenkins, workflow, promoted-builds

I am looking to implement a 'workflow' in Jenkins. I would like -

1. Requester_Jenkins_Job is triggered by the developer. A mail is
   dispatched to the approver.
2. The promotion plugin is used. The
    approver manually 'approves' the request, which in turn triggers the
    'Deploy_Job'.
3. Instead of triggering the 'Deploy_Job' immediately, I
   would want **it to be in queue**. I'd like the operations folks to
   manually trigger this deployment.

One can argue why do we even need to do something like this. But, bear with me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use a rebuild plugin which is very useful : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Rebuild+Plugin

With the help of above plugin , I would suggest following work-around
1. have a Boolean variable , say "deploy"=true/false
2. keep default value false
3. when your build is promoted deploy job will be triggered but it will just notify operation folks and won't actually deploy.
4. with the help of rebuild plugin operation team can trigger "rebuild last" (which will carry out all parameters as from promoted job ) with deploy=true

Hope this helps.